# remove the new line characters to the encoded base64 string

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

Failed to remove the new line characters to the encoded base64 string,

As **CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF** is used but it is not supported in Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP, How to get the desired result in windows xp and 2003 without using **CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF**

```
Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sLen : Cardinal;
  temp : String;
  a : Array[0..1] of Byte = ($00,$00);
Begin
  CryptBinaryToStringA(@a[0],Length(a),CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 Or CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF,nil,@sLen);
  SetLength(temp,sLen);
  CryptBinaryToStringA(@a[0],Length(a),CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 Or CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF ,@temp[1],@sLen);
  ShowMessage(temp);
end;
```

[CryptBinaryToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it just to do this:

```
uses StrUtils;

Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sLen : Cardinal;
  temp : String;
  a : Array[0..1] of Byte = ($00,$00);
Begin
  CryptBinaryToStringA(@a[0],Length(a),CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 Or CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF,nil,@sLen);
  SetLength(temp,sLen);
  CryptBinaryToStringA(@a[0],Length(a),CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 Or CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF ,@temp[1],@sLen);
  temp:=StrReplace(temp,#13#10,'');
  ShowMessage(temp);
end;
```

ie. replace the CR/LF pairs with empty strings to remove it from the output string?